# How to check the signature of generic member function?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I have wrote a gerneric type `Meta`:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
struct Meta
{
  // ...
};
```

And I need to make some `MetaModifier`(s) to build it in compile time.

MetaModifier(s) seem like below:

```cpp
struct FooModifier
{
  template <size_t N, size_t N2>
  Meta<N2> apply(Meta<N> meta)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Some of Modifiers' `apply` will change `Meta<N>` to `Meta<N2>`.

Use case:

```cpp
constexpr Meta<1> default_meta{};

// Call variadic function
constexpr auto meta = apply_modifiers(default_meta, FooModifier{}, BarModifier{});
```

This is my implementation:

```cpp
template <typename Modifier, size_t N>
static constexpr auto apply_modifier(Meta<N> meta, Modifier M)
{
  return M.apply(meta);
}

template <size_t N, typename FirstModifier, typename... RestModifiers>
static constexpr auto apply_modifiers(Meta<N> meta, FirstModifier F, RestModifiers... rest)
{
  return apply_modifiers(apply_modifier(meta, F), rest...);
}

template <size_t N>
static constexpr auto apply_modifiers(Meta<N> meta)
{
  return meta;
}
```

Currently it works, but I want to check types of Modifier(s) to make sure it has a method `Meta<N2> apply(Meta<N>)`, report a friendly message if it is not matched. I tried to make a `concept MetaModifier` but failed. How can I write a correct concept or use some compile time checking to ensure it?

**UPDATE: Is there a way to try two steps like below (pseudo code)?**

```cpp
template <typename Modifier, size_t N>
static constexpr auto apply_modifier(Meta<N> meta, Modifier M)
{
  // First step: test it has a method apply
  if constexpr (has_apply<Modifier, Meta<N>>)
  {
    // Second step: test the return type of apply
    auto r =  M.apply(meta);

    if constexpr (is_meta_type<decltype(r)>)
    {
      return r;
    }
    else
    {
      static_assert(false, "The return type of apply is not Meta<N>");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    static_assert(false, "Modifier does not have apply method");
  }
}
```

Comment: A concept can't quantify over an unbounded set of types and you can't check the signature of a template with them (at least not generally and not without weird hacks). That's not how concepts are intended to be used. They are intended to check whether the specific expressions that e.g. `apply_modifiers` uses on the type are valid and these can only possibly use `apply` with a finite number of known template arguments. `apply_modifiers` should be constraint by a `requires` clause for validity of these expressions and it shouldn't matter whether they are implemented as a template or not.

Comment: Btw. this misunderstanding comes up regularly. I am sure there are many similar questions that are at the core the same.

Comment: *"`return M.apply(meta);`"* -- How does `N2` factor in here? It's not deducible from the argument.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there a way to try two steps?
```c++
template <typename Modifier, size_t N>
static constexpr auto apply_modifier(Meta<N> meta, Modifier M)
{
  // First step: test it has a method apply
  if constexpr (has_apply<Modifier, Meta<N>>)
  {
    // Second step: test the return type of apply
    auto r =  M.apply(meta);

    if constexpr (is_meta_type<decltype(r)>)
    {
      return r;
    }
    else
    {
      static_assert(false, "The return type is not Meta<N>");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    static_assert(false, "Does not have apply method");
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the question, How does N2 factor in here? It's not deducible from the argument. Unless the `Modifiier` Is not like what you show...

Comment: `N2` provided by `Modifier::apply`, because `Meta<n>` has a `std::array<size_t, N>` field, some `Modifier` type will change its size(returning new one). This field save some metadata, and use them to build static type multi-dimensions array. The full code is too long, a similar case likely `Tensor<std::array<size_t, 3>{2, 3, 4}> t; t.reshape<std::array<size_t, 3>{2, 3, 2, 2}>()`. It just pack dimensions to a parameter instead variadic template parameters, I abstracted the `Modifier` to build these kind usage, other modifiers maybe change the tensor data type, and other static props.

Comment: The real code in this case likely: `Tensor<shape(2,3,4), dtype(FLOAT32)> tensor; tensor.reshape<shape(2,3,2,2)>();`, `shape` and `dtype` just makes `ShapeModifier` and `TypeModifier`, And `Tensor` is a variadic template, accepts many `Modifier` const args, and call `apply_modifiers` to make final meta in compile time. And I also want to support `tensor.reshape(shape(2,3,2,2))` for more friendly.

Comment: You don't need to create a variable just to capture its type. Instead of `auto r =  M.apply(meta); ... decltype(r)` you can do just `decltype(M.apply(meta))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept is there to check if a type satisfies some property. It can't check if a template satisfies some property, because a template isn't a type.

`apply_modifier` needs to know which `N2` to use when it is passed a `FooModifier`, the easiest way is to make `N2` a template argument of `FooModifier`.

```
template <size_t N2>
struct FooModifier
{
  template <size_t N>
  Meta<N2> apply(Meta<N> meta)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Another possibility is that `N2` is dependant on `N`, e.g.

```
struct BarModifier
{
  template <size_t N>
  Meta<N + 1> apply(Meta<N> meta)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Having done that, we can construct constraints for `apply_modifier` and `apply_modifiers`

```
template <typename T>
struct is_meta : std::false_type {};

template <size_t N>
struct is_meta<Meta<N>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
concept meta = is_meta<T>::value;

template <typename Mod, typename M>
concept meta_modifier = meta<M> && requires(Mod mod, M m)
{
  { mod.apply(m) } -> meta;
}
```

Our `meta_modifier` concept requires knowing the `Meta` that it will modify, which means that you can still check modifiers that only apply to certain `Meta` specialisations

```
template <meta M, meta_modifier<M> Modifier>
static constexpr auto apply_modifier(M meta, Modifier modifier)
{
  return modifier.apply(meta);
}

template <meta M, meta_modifier<M> FirstModifier, typename... RestModifiers>
static constexpr auto apply_modifiers(M meta, FirstModifier F, RestModifiers... rest)
{
  return apply_modifiers(apply_modifier(meta, F), rest...);
}

template <meta M>
static constexpr auto apply_modifiers(M meta)
{
  return meta;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This's acceptable for me. But I got a compiling error: `error: concept cannot have associated constraints. concept meta_modifier = requires(Mod mod, M m) {`, what's that means? how can I solve it?

Comment: @JackyLee oops, had incorrect syntax for that concept, see edit

Comment: That's perfect!